# {"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":8100}

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, katalon-studio

I want to automate native app in `appium` but I'm not able to connect to appium server through my code,I'm getting the below exception on appium console:

> "errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":8100}"

can someone help?

Comment: well, is your server listening at localhost:8100? doesn't seem like it is

Comment: if I manually set 8100 in my appium, next time when I run test, it connects to new random port

Comment: try uninstalling WebDriverAgentRunner app from your device and try

Comment: @sam have you found a fix for this issue? I'm running into the same problem